# Password for mifare classic authentication

Tags: authentication, nfc, mifare

I have to authenticate an mifare classic 4k with an password, that are generated with 3DES out of KeyA and KeyB (like described here in the picture on top: http://gelvaos.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-to-calculate-mifare-password.html).

Is there any tool that do that (you enter keyA and keyB and the mifare password is coming out)? 
Here is an example: 
KeyA: FF FF FF FF FF FF
KeyB: FF FF FF FF FF FF

Mifare Password: 0B 54 57 07 45 FE 3A E7

Can you please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else is looking for that, here is an really cool github project for exactly this calculation: https://github.com/gelvaos/MifarePass/tree/master/MifarePass

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [openSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), which can be used to implement such type of computation from the command line.

Comment: Sounds awesome...do you have an example for doing that?